# Running WSL on Windows 10, GUIs will not display

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to run WSL Ubuntu on my Windows 10 PC. I have Ubuntu and Xming installed, and have been trying to run gedit on the WSL. I've done the same basic installation thats common for Xming and WSL, I've updated WSL multiple times, and still no success.

My process was generally:

1. Install WSL
2. Install Xming
3. Run Xming via Xlaunch with basic setup
4. export DISPLAY=:0.0 (I've tried numerous variations of this)
5. Install gedit
6. Run gedit

The error I get is:

'''Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gedit:44): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:47:20.284: cannot open display: :0.0'''

Please help, I'm at my wits end.

UPDATE:
I reinstalled it and realized that the WSL version was WSL 2, so setting it to WSL 1 fixed the problem.

Comment: have you installed X Server for the host?

Comment: @arslan2012 I think so, what would that entail?

Comment: WSL is not intended to run a desktop environment.

Comment: Do you have the problem *only* with gedit? does a simple client like `xeyes` work?

Comment: @Nmath I don't have an option

Comment: @steeldriver xeyes didnt work but I got it fixed

Comment: @Nmath Thank you for the advice, I posted my own answer below. Could I ask why you said it’s not intended to run in a desktop environment? What was it intended to run in?

Comment: It was *never* intended to run a desktop, but to allow developers to use Linux command line utilities to interact within the Windows installation (as opposed to a VM or dual-boot) See: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq#can-i-run-all-linux-apps-in-wsl

Answer (score 2):

The fix I had to do was change it to WSL 1. That’s the whole issue I had, because I didn’t know WSL 2 was setup by default for Ubuntu. For anyone else who might have this problem, make sure to always check the version.